# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError ResponseHanlder apache tomcat

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tomcat8, spark-java

I meet at the moment a problem in my project.
I explain the context.
I conceived Web Service with the framework Sparkjava http://sparkjava.com
Then I generated one to do war.
But when I deploy my application on tomcat Apache and when I start him, I obtain this error OK- Application not deployed for the path of context.
In the file log Localhost, I have this error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.wialon.remote.handlers.ResponseHandler.

**pom.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>transplusafrica</groupId>
<artifactId>api-delydress</artifactId>
<version>0.0.6</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>WebServiceDelyDress</name>

<properties>
    <properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.testTarget>1.8</maven.compiler.testTarget>
    <maven.compiler.testSource>1.8</maven.compiler.testSource>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-compile</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                        <compilerArguments>
                            <source>${maven.compiler.target}</source>
                            <target>${maven.compiler.source}</target>
                        </compilerArguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-testCompile</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                        <compilerArguments>
                            <source>${maven.compiler.testTarget}</source>
                            <target>${maven.compiler.testSource}</target>
                        </compilerArguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/web.xml</packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
        <artifactId>converter-gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
        <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160212</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**web.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <web-app version="3.0"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<display-name>WebServiceDelyDress</display-name>

<filter>
    <filter-name>SparkFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>spark.servlet.SparkFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>applicationClass</param-name>
        <param-value>transplus.MainSpark</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SparkFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

[I placed my two bookshops which I use in the file Webapp/lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqWbT.png)

The problem is that files .Classe of my two Jar are not created.
You can help me to solve this problem.

NB : IDE- Intellij Idea; Server : Tomcat8

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to add your bookshop jar files as "local dependency" in pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.sample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/yourJar.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank Thank for the solution

Answer (score 0):

While building application maven ignores the dependencies which are added not added by maven.  you have provided the Wilson sdk in your lib path, but once war is prepared it won't have the Wilsonjar in it. Try to add it as a maven dependency.

If your building this application only for the learning purpose then you can go to m2 folder and you can create a maven dummy maven structure which will work only in your system. That way you will have the dependency jar always available inside your war.

Or else go to your tomcat folder and find your application add this jar file inside lib folder of your application directory.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance